# How to disable default selection for programmatically added ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am dynamically adding a listview in my activity layout. The problem I am facing is : when the listview is populated, it shows first item as selected and since I have used a selector, it highlights the default selection. I wish to know ,what needs to be added in code, so that none of the items is selected by default.

Here is the code snippet of how I am adding listview dynamically.

```
            ListView dynamicListView = new ListView(this);  
    HierarchicalListAdapter hierarchicalListAdapter = new HierarchicalListAdapter(this, hierarchicalList);
    dynamicListView.setAdapter(hierarchicalListAdapter);
    dynamicListView.setOnItemClickListener(hierarchicalListAdapter);
    hierarchicalListAdapter.setItems(items);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dynamicListView.setCacheColorHint(0);
    dynamicListView.setDivider(null);
    dynamicListView.setDividerHeight(1);    
    dynamicListView.setSelector(R.color.list_item_higlight_color);
    dynamicListView.setLayoutParams(params);    

    mainListViewLayout.addView(dynamicListView, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamicListView.setItemChecked(0,false);
```

Comment: I tried this but it isn't working. I found that for this to work, listview row layout needs to be Chekable. I am not sure how to do that.